# Fix Horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript

I want my script to scroll horizontally when it reaches the desired container, and when it finishes it scrolls vertically again, the problem is when you scroll again and reach the container, the horizontal scroll does not work, how do I make it work every time you go through the container?

```
        const cont = document.querySelector(".cont");
        const cont_hidden = document.querySelector(".cont_hidden");
        function scroll_vertical_on(event) {
            if (event.deltaY !== 0 && cont.scrollWidth > cont.clientWidth) {
                cont.scrollLeft += event.deltaY * 2;
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log("Vertical funcionando");
            }
        }
        function scroll_horizontal_on(event) {
            if (event.deltaY !== 0 && cont.scrollHeight > cont.clientHeight) {
                cont.scrollTop += event.deltaY * 2;
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log("Horizontal funcionando");
            }
        }
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
            if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
                cont.addEventListener("wheel", scroll_vertical_on);
                console.log("Observer cont funcionando");
            }
        });
        const observer_hidden = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
            if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
                cont.removeEventListener("wheel", scroll_vertical_on);
                cont.addEventListener("wheel", scroll_horizontal_on);
            }
        });
        observer.observe(cont);
        observer_hidden.observe(cont_hidden);
```

Comment: Can you create a running example to demonstrate? Use the `<>` button to make your code a runnable snippet with HTML, CSS, JS etc.